# Is this 肠 a mistaken character?

Tags: meaning

Is this 肠 a typo in my book？

这次探明了大石围天坑是集地下溶洞、地下原始森林、珍稀动植物以及地下暗河于一体的世界第二大天坑。 短肠蕨类植物比恐龙时期的桫椤还要古老。

短**肠**蕨类 ： short *intestined* fern

Can 肠 refer to the trunk of a tree, the stem of a plant or somehow the length of the leaves??

Comment: 肠 is from the shape of its sorus.

Comment: Thanks. Is that also their name in English/Latin? 'filix intestina brevis' Glad I'm not a botanist!

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not a typo, surely there is a kind of plant called 短肠蕨, the latin name of which is Allantodia.

Details can be found at: http://www.eflora.cn/sp/Allantodia

Comment: Aha, just a name then? Thanks!